# encoding categorical variables in libsvm

Tags: java, encoding, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

Is there a class in libsvm that can automatically encode string/categorical features. I found something called libsvmstringoutcomedatawriter. Which type of encoding does the above use? One hot encoding ?

Comment: Cleartk libsvm has the class ibsvmstringoutcomedatawriter..

Answer (score 0):

How your features should be encoded for LibSVM depends on the kernel you use with  SVM. For instance, string kernels exist which allow you to use strings as features with SVMs directly. [LibSVM FAQ](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/#libsvm_for_string_data) discusses an implementation of a string kernel which can be used with LibSVM. I also found a [string kernel implementation in Python](https://github.com/timshenkao/StringKernelSVM), although haven't tested it.

Regarding categorical features, those can be used with the standard kernels available in LibSVM. A typical way of encoding categorical features is to convert them to binary features, where each categorical value is represented as value `1` of a specific feature. For instance, for a feature `color={red, green, blue}`, we can have 3 features `red={0,1}`, `green={0,1}`, `blue={0,1}`. Then, kernels such as Gaussian/RBF should be able to handle the data without problems.

Comment: But do I have to do this encoding manually ? And I am trying to encode features which are POS tags. Any details on them?